# Is it possible to filter Google PubSub's pubsub_subscription by labels other than project_id or subscription_id?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to build a metrics query that will return the `num_undelivered_messages` for subscriptions based on labels other than the resource `pubsub_subscription`'s provided labels `subscription_id` and `project_id`. For example, I would like to filter by a label already set on subscriptions in GCP console, `product_type`, such as

```
String filter
    = "metric.type=\"pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/num_undelivered_messages\" 
       resource.type=\"pubsub_subscription\"
       resource.label.\"product_type\"=\"productA\"";
```

Based off of the `MetricServiceClient.ListTimeSeriesPagedResponse` I get back after querying without `product_type`, the only labels provided are the aforementioned `project_id` and `subscription_id` in the `pubsub_subscription` monitored resource descriptor, no labels in the `num_undelivered_messages` metric descriptor, and no metadata labels defined.

Is there some kind of configuration for `MetricServiceClient` or `ListTimeSeriesRequest` that I can set in order to filter by `product_type`?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the Cloud monitoring or Pubsub?

Comment: Hey @Adebisi, I'm trying to do this in java using the cloud monitoring API, so with `MetricServiceClient` and `ListTimeSeriesRequest`. With that I'm trying to get the information from the resource `pubsub_subscription` filtered by a label other than the labels `project_id` and `subscription_id`

Comment: From the research I carried out, it appears we don't have support for the one you requested other than  labels project_id and subscription_id in the resource pubsub_subscription. Labels generally used for [cost purposes](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending)